# Save export from range in excel to Word and save as name in Cell A1

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am now exporting a range of cells into Word using a macro in excel.

There are some changes though as I need it to instead copy this to a NEW Word document and not an existing one that is in the script?

My range that is selected is made up of various Vlookup results.

Also, if possible, I want to get the file name to be whatever is in A1.

```
Sub Export_Table_Data_Word()
    'Name of the existing Word document
    Const stWordDocument As String = "Table Report.docx"

    'Word objects.
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdCell As Word.Cell

    'Excel objects
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

    'Count used in a FOR loop to fill the Word table.
    Dim lnCountItems As Long

    'Variant to hold the data to be exported.
    Dim vaData As Variant

    'Initialize the Excel objects
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    vaData = wsSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value

    'Instantiate Word and open the "Table Reports" document.
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\" & stWordDocument)

    lnCountItems = 1

    'Place the data from the variant into the table in the Word doc.
    For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells
        wdCell.Range.Text = vaData(lnCountItems, 1)
        lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
    Next wdCell

    'Save and close the Word doc.
    With wdDoc
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

    wdApp.Quit

    'Null out the variables.
    Set wdCell = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "The " & stWordDocument & "'s table has succcessfully " & vbNewLine & _
           "been updated!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Thank you Nicholas for the assistance. Below the final script:

```
Sub OLDMACROADJUSTED()

'Word objects.
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdCell As Word.Cell

'Excel objects
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

'Count used in a FOR loop to fill the Word table.
Dim lnCountItems As Long

'Variant to hold the data to be exported.
Dim vaData As Variant

'File path based on A1'
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\FolderName\" & Cells(1, 1).Value & ".doc"

'Initialize the Excel objects
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
vaData = wsSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value

'Instantiate Word and open the new file.
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add 'Create new app instead of open'


lnCountItems = 1

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("B3:B7")
wrdDoc.Content.InsertAfter c
Next c


'Place the data from the variant into the table in the Word doc.
'For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells
'wdCell.Range.Text = vaData(lnCountItems, 1)
'lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
'Next wdCell

'Save and close the Word doc.
With wrdDoc
If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then
Kill filePath
End If
.SaveAs (Range("B3").Value)
.Close ' close the document
End With

'wdApp.Quit

'Null out the variables.
Set wdCell = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Your file has been saved in default location of the macro...", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out:

```
Sub Export_Table_Data_Word()

    'Name of the existing Word document
    ' Const stWordDocument As String = "Table Report.docx"

    'Word objects.
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdCell As Word.Cell

    'Excel objects
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

    'Count used in a FOR loop to fill the Word table.
    Dim lnCountItems As Long

    'Variant to hold the data to be exported.
    Dim vaData As Variant

    'File path based on A1'
    Dim filePath As String
        filePath = "C:\FolderName\" & Cells(1, 1).Value & ".doc"

    'Initialize the Excel objects
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    vaData = wsSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value

    'Instantiate Word and open the new file.
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add 'Create new app instead of open'


    lnCountItems = 1

    'Place the data from the variant into the table in the Word doc.
    For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells
        wdCell.Range.Text = vaData(lnCountItems, 1)
        lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
    Next wdCell

    'Save and close the Word doc.
    With wrdDoc 
        If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then 
            Kill filePath 
        End If 
        .SaveAs (filePath) 
        .Close ' close the document
    End With 

    wdApp.Quit

    'Null out the variables.
    Set wdCell = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "The " & stWordDocument & "'s table has succcessfully " & vbNewLine & _
           "been updated!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

All that I changed was adding a `filePath` variable to store the file path (including the value found in `A1`), changed `wdDoc` to be a new document instead of opening an old one, and reconfigured the saving of the file to make sure the file isn't open before trying to save.

[Here's where I got the most of the code.](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=50936)

**Test code:**

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc() 
     ' to test this code, paste it into an Excel module
     ' add a reference to the Word-library
     ' create a new folder named C:\Foldername or edit the filnames in the code
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application 
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document 
    Dim i As Integer 
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    wrdApp.Visible = True 
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add 
     ' or
     'Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Foldername\Filename.doc")
     ' sample word operations
    With wrdDoc 
        For i = 1 To 100 
            .Content.InsertAfter "Here is a sample test line #" & i 
            .Content.InsertParagraphAfter 
        Next i 
        If Dir("C:\Foldername\MyNewWordDoc.doc") <> "" Then 
            Kill "C:\Foldername\MyNewWordDoc.doc" 
        End If 
        .SaveAs ("C:\Foldername\MyNewWordDoc.doc") 
        .Close ' close the document
    End With 
    wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing 
    Set wrdApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I get User-defined type not defined error? And then it highlights the dim wdapp part? How can I correct this @nicholas

Comment: I have also added Word under references, really stuck here? @nicholas

Comment: @user4242750 Just updated the post with how the `wrdApp` variable gets set.

Comment: Still giving me the same error in the same place? @nicholas. Is this a usual problem? I just see on all pages to just turn my references to word on in this case. Thanks for your help i appreciate it. Is there anything I must change from your code above?

Comment: Try running the example code I linked to in the post, not the code I posted in my comment just to make sure everything is set up properly and you have Word linked correctly.

Comment: Ok I have done so @nicholas, one doesn't. the one that does work is: Sub M_snb() 
    With CreateObject("Word.Document") 
        .Windows(1).Visible = True 
        .Content = "Example" 
    End With 
End Sub

Comment: So you ran the code that I just posted as "test code"? What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81450/discussion-between-user4242750-and-nicholas79171).