# Excel VBA code to convert all PDF files into Word files

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance.

Please help as I am stuck with VBA code which can convert all PDF file into Word.

Convert means Convert not to Export or SaveAs .The code is working well, but it's not what I am looking for as I need to convert instead of saving.

```
File=Dir(Path & "*.pdf*")

Do While (File <> "")

Documents.Open FileName:= Path & File

With ActiveDocument 
Application.DisplayAlerts=False
.SaveAs2 FileName:=Replace(Path & File,".pdf", ".docx"), _
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
.Close
Application.Displayalerts=True
End With

File=Dir

Loop
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with *Convert* that is not handled with the `SaveAs2` command?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358704/4717755) is rather clear that you must have Adobe Acrobat installed to convert from PDF to Word, and shows the supporting code.

Comment: Hi FunThomas, Convert like we do graphically export PDf into different format. Through word am getting format issue. Like extra lines are getting merged. Might be the author who has made pdf did not hit enter while typing in Word first which later saved in PDF. Now those lines without enter are going back to end of the last text used. If there is any other solution by which I can keep orinal formatting i would really appreciate

Comment: Hi PeterT yes I have. But needed VBA code here